# can't click button on my game flash in firefox

Tags: actionscript-3, firefox, flash

I make a simple game and try to upload it on my website. My game has a button to click with a mouse when you wanna play it. I already finish upload my game, but when I want to test the game I cant click the button on my game. The button doesn't respond. Any helps?

```
<div class="container">

    <!-- Outer Row -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-lg-5">

        <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
          <div class="card-body p-0">
              <object width="720" height="1280">
                  <param name="movie" value="game_bk.swf">

                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                  <embed src="http://mi5a01.elektro-pnb.com/file_flash/game_bk.swf" width="720" height="1280"></embed>
              </object>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Apparently this hasn't anything to do with the upload to your website - the button also doesn't respond if I download the file and try it offline. Does it work if you try to preview your game In Flash's IDE?

Comment: It works, but rarely when I run the game, I get an error that some objects are not found. Although I had assured making the object. Fyi, I use AS3 on Flash CS6 and some scenes @obscure